# PHP Hide sub-folders from SCANDIR

Tags: php, file, directory, hidden-files

I'm using the [jQuery FileTree plugin](https://github.com/daverogers/jQueryFileTree). The php connector uses scandir to get a folder's contents. After I upload images, my uploader script creates a "thumbs" folder, and then makes a thumbnail version of the image, and stores it there.

Users will be operating on the files within each image folder, but I don't really want them seeing the "thumbs" folder that's within each image folder. I could move the thumbs folder to some other place, but that would be kind of a huge undertaking.

Is there a way to make the "thumbs" folder my upload script creates a hidden folder, unseeable by scandir?

```
$files  = scandir($postDir);
$returnDir  = substr($postDir, strlen($root));
```

[image]

Comment: In php you can use is_dir to check each thing found by scandir, and remove it from the array. Not sure if this is useful in jquery though.

Comment: The actual code that will be doing the filtering is a php script. It is the "connector" that works to provide the jquery with the files list.

Comment: It looks to me like with that connector you can just send a hidden field "onlyFiles" with a value of true to accomplish what you want. Or comment out line 57.

Comment: See Matt Gibson's answer below. It is the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a custom version of [jQueryFileTree's php connector](https://github.com/jqueryfiletree/jqueryfiletree/blob/master/dist/connectors/jqueryFileTree.php), adding your exclusion to the filtering, around line 55:

```
if( file_exists($postDir . $file) && $file != '.' && $file != '..' && $file != 'thumbs') {
```

Then use that script instead of the standard connector by passing its name as the `script` parameter to the `fileTree` function when creating the tree on the JS side.

(Depending on what states your directories can be in, e.g. whether you'll always have a "thumb" folder, etc., you may also need to adjust the `if( count($files) > 2 )`, but this should give you the basic principle -- just create your own connector and customise it as necessary.)